# Problem with definition of amplitude of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $a$ and $b$ are respectively the minimum and maximum values of function $h$ then the amplitude of $h$ is: $$\frac{b-a}{2}$$
Why is this true?

Comment: This is, in my opinion, true because it's the very _definition_ of amplitude. What's _your_ definition?

Comment: @Arthur The amplitude of a periodic function is the distance above the line in which the graph is centered.

Answer (score 1):

"The amplitude of a periodic function is the distance above the line in which the graph is centered."

That's your own definition. We can use that to see why this is the answer.

The curve hits troughs at $a$ and peaks at $b$. So the centre line has to lie exactly between them. That's at the mean of the two, and hence lies at $\displaystyle \frac{a+b}{2}$.

Now the amplitude is the distance between the peak and the centre line, which is $\displaystyle b - \frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{2b-a-b}{2} = \frac{b-a}{2}$, as required.

You can repeat the calculation between the trough and the centre line to get the same result in case you want to convince yourself.